# How to execute three thread simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my code which i tried but my main class is not there because i don't know how to use that one

```
//first thread

class firstthread extends Thread
{
   public void run(){
     for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
     {
          System.out.println(i);
     }}
}

//second thread

class secondthread extends Thread
{
   public void run(){
     for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
     {
          System.out.println(i);
     }}
}
```

Comment: p.s. You don't use the backticks for blocks of code. Just the indentation is enough.

Comment: I suggest you start by learning the basics of Java syntax and semantics. When you are able to at least write compilable code, you'll be in a much better position to start playing with multithreading (although far from knowing what you're doing).

Comment: The code as it stands is having syntax errors. You can have a for directly inside a class block. First get the base sequential code correct and then you can look into running them parallelly.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you have written is incomplete code, to create a thread you need to extend Thread class or implement Runnable interface and then override its `public void run()` method.

To create a thread you need to override the method `public void run`

Then to start the threads you need to call its `start()` method.

### A simple complete example

```
class MyThread extends Thread {
   String name;
   public void run(){
      for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
         System.out.println("Thread name :: "+name+" : "i);
     }
   }
}
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        MyThread t1 = new MyThread();
        t1.name = "Thread ONE";
        MyThread t2 = new MyThread();
        t2.name = "Thread TWO";
        MyThread t3 = new MyThread();
        t3.name = "Thread THREE";
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First overide the run method and then create the object of thread class in main()
and call start method.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for(int y=0;y<1000;y++)
                 {
                      System.out.println(y);
                 }
            };
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just put some code in your class body.

You need a method to have the code in, the method being `run()` in case of thread.

Instead of copy-pasting the code, I'll point you to the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) where you can find some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Sample program given below. Since there is no synchronization code, there output is mixed from the three threads

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": ");
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    System.out.println();

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        new Thread(new ThreadTest()).start();
    }
}
}
```